# return and display a value passed to component in a card

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**Card.js**

```
const Card = () => {
 const { CardStyle, HeadingStyle, bottomStyle, Top } = styles;
 return (
<View style={CardStyle}>
  {/* {props.children}  */}

  <CardTitle titleText={"Feedback"} EditButton={true} />
  {/* <CardTitle titleText={"My Skills"} EditButton={false} /> */}

  <View />
  <SeeMore />
</View>
 );
  };
```

**component in card to take the parameter and display views**

```
const CardTitle = ({ titleText, EditButton = false }) => {
  const { HeadingStyle, TitleStyle } = styles;
 if (EditButton == true) {
<Text style={HeadingStyle}>Edit</Text>;
 }
 return (
<View style={TitleStyle}>
  <Text style={HeadingStyle}>
    {titleText}
   </Text>
      </View>
   );
   };
```

The value I'm passing, i.e in Card.js the `titleText` "Feedback" won't print in my card display?

How do I print the "Feedback" word passed from the card? ***kinda Solved***

Comment: You aren't pulling in your props correctly. It should be more like `CardTitle = ({ titleText, EditButton }) => { ...`

Comment: thanks @MikeC !! it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just with:

```
const CardTitle = (titleText, EditButton = { False }) => {
    const { HeadingStyle, TitleStyle } = styles;
    if (EditButton) {
    }
    return (
        <View style={TitleStyle}>
            <Text style={HeadingStyle}>
                {titleText.titleText}
            </Text>

            <Text style={HeadingStyle}>Edit</Text>
        </View>
    );
};
```

But it should be

```
const CardTitle = (props) => {
    ...
    {props.titleText}
    ...
}
```